# Android target compatability issues?

Tags: android, version, compatibility

if we develop our Android application with target Android2.1-update1,can we install that application in Android1.6 version devices?

My intention is  to use Android2.1-update1 target for my application,and i want to make itinstallable in all Android devices.at run time i want to know the device version and want to handle code accordingly.how to do this?please help.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `with target Android2.1-update1,can we install that application in
   Android1.6 version devices?`

**ans ::** No

2  `i want to make it installable in all Android devices.`

**ans::**

```
       1. try to impement your project in lowest version

       2. make sure that component or method you have use are already exist in
          minimum api level     e. g ::  MediaPlayer has method `setAudioSessionId()`  are not use < 9 but you can use `seekTo()` in all.

       3. set your api level lowest
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.actually i want to implement multi touch feature to my applictaion. for that i must target atleast 2.1 version. at the same time my application should be able to run in Android 1.6 version devices too(without multi touch).how it can be solved?